# Is there any proof in Number theory claimed or dis-claimed the existence of universel form generating primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, closed-form

Many students , teachers  of mathematics provide a huge efforts to get a universal closed form of a function which generate prime number , Really i'm very interesting to know if there is any proof claim or dis-claim the existence of Universal closed form of generating prime function and also i don't want wasting my time with that if it dosn't exists ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html

Comment: I saw that  , i asked about  proof which claim the existence of unic formula for which generates primes or dis-claim it

Comment: See [formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) here. It looks like it's unknown whether a function exists, or doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem is that there is no accepted definition of what a "formula for primes" would be. The Wikipedia article John shows that some kinds of formulas are impossible, while some are (see the MathWorld article). If you want a more specific answer, try to specify what would count as a "closed form" to you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes   This article may help.

Comment: There are many posts here on this topics, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940338/the-myth-of-no-prime-formula), and others.

Comment: I wonder how the proof on an infinite number of primes would work here. That is, take the product of all known primes and add one, this is either a new prime or a composite of new primes. I wonder if this would skip any primes?